# How to get period after move number for chess game with xskak and chessboard

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, skak

I'm using xskak and chessboard to typeset a game.  I would like to have a period after each move number such as "1. e4" rather than just "1 e4"
How can I achieve this with xskak and chessboard?  My current output and MWE are shown below
[image]

Here is the MWE for this game:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}\\
\chessboard[label=False]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to dig into the [documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/xskak/xskak.pdf). On page 44 it talks about creating your own style, which they called `test`. So I took their name and changed the colors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\xskaknewstyleitem[%
template=UF,%a predefined style item
beforenumber=\color{black},%
whiteopen=.\,\color{black},
blackopen=\ldots\,\color{black}]{rednumbers}
\xskakaddtostyle[%
level=10,
styleitem=rednumbers,
level=12,
font=\def\beforenumber{\color{black}}\bfseries]
{test}
\begin{preview}
\newchessgame
\mainline[style=test,level=12]{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3  a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}\\
\chessboard[label=False]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

This is the output in Gummi (click on picture to enlarge).
[image]

Comment: all this color commands are not really necessary, black is the default color.

Comment: Thanks!  From the documentation it looks like "level" corresponds to the variation level, is that right?  The example right after the one you modeled after has level=gobbleB,styleitem=gobblecomments, do you know what that means?

Comment: Are there other templates or do we always choose UF?

Comment: The documentation says, page 47, five styles: A , B, C, UF, and test. Whichever style suits you best. Looks like "level" corresponds to variation level but Ulricke Fischer would know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the style UF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\xskakset{style=UF}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}\\
\chessboard[label=False]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation needs some updating with complete working MWEs like what you have above. The examples I found on page 6 and 8 didn't compile because of missing style files. The code snippets (eg page 15) that had periods after numbers in output weren't helping because, it seems, there was no `\xskakset` in the snippet.

Comment: @DJP if you find errors, add an issue at  https://github.com/u-fischer/xskak, (there is no code yet, I just open the repo there).

Answer (score 0):

Using the notation `\styleA` to pag. 12 of the documentation of [skak](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/skak/doc/skakdoc.pdf) package: (The `\styleA` will switch the typesetting to the way it has been the **standard in
Denmark** and — **I believe** — **Germany**.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\usepackage{parskip}
\notationoff
\styleA
\showmoverOn
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3  a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}
\storegame{game1}
\[ \showboard \]
\end{document}
```

you have "*a period after each move number such as "1. e4*"" with a comma.

[image]