# skak xskak board orientation

Tags: xskak, skak

I found a line "in standard board orientation" but not the option to have a flipped board orientation. Can I have a board displayed for black's view?

Answer (score 3):

This is more about the `chessboard` package than `xskak`. Just put `inverse` in the options when you invoke `\chessboard`. Modifying the code from the MWE [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488000/how-to-get-period-after-move-number-for-chess-game-with-xskak-and-chessboard) we'd have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6     5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}\\
\chessboard[inverse,label=False]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The result in Gummi is:
[image]
You can find this in the documentation of the `chessboard` package [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf) in section 5.2. I've deleted the line `\usepackage{chessboard}` since the documentation for `xskak` [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/xskak/xskak.pdf) says on page 7,
"The package xskak uses some primitives of eTEX. It needs version 1.4 or version 1.5 of the
package skak , a recent version of the package chessfss (chess font selection) and xkeyval
(key=value-syntax), version 1.5 of chessboard (which in turns needs pgf ) and xifthen".

**EDIT:** This would generate the output on the full page, rather than like a diagram as shown above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4.  Nxd4 Nf6     5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}
\chessboard[inverse]
\end{document}
```

The result in Gummi is:
[image]

Smaller screenshot:

[image]

If you don't want the moves, replace mainline moves with `\hidemoves{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4.  Nxd4 Nf6     5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6 7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}`.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Any particular reason that you include the code and the empty space around the document in your screenshot?

Comment: The only reason is I borrowed code from a post using `xkak` which showed the position from the white perspective so I could change it to a black perspective. I had to revise my answer when I realized `\usepackage{chessboard}` was included. The `\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}` can also be deleted.

Comment: I wasn't wondering about the code itself (that looks fine as it is), the question was why the result screenshot is not just the chessboard with the game progression, but instead includes also the large gray area around the pdf view, and the editor view with the code in it, I guess that is not really needed for the answer (because the code is already given in the code block above the screenshot), and just the board and the progression would be more clear (same goes for your linked answer).

Comment: I'm not sure. I posted code to avoid that in my edited post above. Maybe it was due to the `tightpage` option?

Comment: I have added a smaller screenshot to your post to show what I mean. If you disagree with it you can remove it of course, I thought it would be faster to make an edit than to try to explain it in comments.

Comment: If you check any of my posts that have code over the last few of years you'll see the same thing. I started doing that after seeing others (and probably doing it myself) posting code that didn't match the output probably due to multiple revisions. Being able to link the code to the output keeps me from making more mistakes.